# sleep inside inotifywait in a shell function not working

Tags: zsh, sleep, inotifywait

I am trying to run the following function

```sh
foo () {
    sleep 1
    echo "outside inotify"
    (inotifywait . -e create |
    while read path action file; do
        echo "test"
        sleep 1
    done)
    echo "end"
}
```

Until inotifywait it runs correctly; I see:

```sh
>> foo
outside inotify
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

However as soon as I create a file, I get

```sh
>>> fooo
outside inotify
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
test
foo:6: command not found: sleep
end
```

Any idea why? Plus do I need to spawn the subprocess ( ) around inotifywait? what are the benefits?

thank you.

**Edit**
I realized I am running on zsh

Comment: Is `sleep` a loadable builtin by any chance? Run `type sleep` to find out.

Comment: Thank you oguz. `type sleep` returns "sleep is /bin/sleep"

Comment: That's really weird. If you ever find out the problem please let me know

Comment: I just realized I am running on a machine with zsh. I tested with bash and works correctly

Comment: Re: the subprocess, pipelines *always* start one. If you didn't make it explicit, you'd still have one anyhow. Having it be explicit in the code makes it clear to readers that variables they set in the `while read` loop won't be accessible anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read path` is messing you up, because unlike POSIX-compliant shells -- which guarantee that only modification to variables with all-uppercase names can have unwanted side effects on the shell itself -- zsh also has special-cased behavior for several lower-case names, including `path`.

In particular, zsh presents `path` as an array corresponding to the values in `PATH`. Assigning a string to this array will overwrite your `PATH` as well.

Comment: @oguzismail, you were interested in what this turned out to be?